# Java Key Bindings and Arrow Keys

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array

Im writing a small top-down game with a player who moves through a two-dimensional array, controlled by the arrow keys.
I must've looked at every tutorial there is on key bindings, but I can't get my keybindings to update the main 'floor' object. help! Sorry for the wall of text, but I think the context of the three files is helpful. thanks!

**EDIT: SSCCE**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package palace.hero;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SSCCE 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();

        int xCoord = 0;
        int yCoord = 0;

        //Key Bindings        
        gridPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "up");
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("up", new SSCCEKA(xCoord, yCoord, "up"));
        gridPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "down");
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("down", new SSCCEKA(xCoord, yCoord, "down"));
        gridPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("left", new SSCCEKA(xCoord, yCoord, "left"));
        gridPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("right", new SSCCEKA(xCoord, yCoord, "right"));

        //Window
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int windowHeight = 1125;
        int windowWidth = 900;
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowHeight, windowWidth));

        window.add(gridPanel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        gridPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package palace.hero;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SSCCEKA extends AbstractAction
{
    String direction;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public SSCCEKA(int x, int y, String direction) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(direction.toLowerCase().equals("up"))
        {
            x++;
        }
        if(direction.toLowerCase().equals("down"))
        {
            x--;
        }
        if(direction.toLowerCase().equals("left"))
        {
            y--;
        }
        if(direction.toLowerCase().equals("right"))
        {
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that the key presses are not detected or something else? (If so, it should be trivial to construct an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: no, they are being detected, i just don't know how to give the 'actionPreformed' function from AbstractAction have side effects. (i've got it to work with printing "up,down,left,right" , but I want it to actually change the floor object in the main class...)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could boil down your issue... See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: fixed it. So in this example, how would i get the key-bindings to affect the xcoord and yCoord in the main class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create anything as complicated as a game, you should use the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

So, let's create a model class.

```
public class GameModel {

    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;

    public int getxCoordinate() {
        return xCoordinate;
    }

    public void setxCoordinate(int xCoordinate) {
        this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
    }

    public int getyCoordinate() {
        return yCoordinate;
    }

    public void setyCoordinate(int yCoordinate) {
        this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    }

}
```

You can pass the GameModel class to your SSCCEKA class through the constructor.

Remember, only controller classes may modify the game model.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but how would you call the constructor every time a button is pressed? (What i'm really asking is how do I allow the actionPressed function to edit the gameModel?)

Comment: @Haskelier:  I'm assuming you're talking about the GameModel constructor.  You call it once somewhere in the beginning of the GUI constructor and pass the instance to the SSCCEKA class so the actionPressed method has access to the GameModel instance.  Here's a [Dice Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=460) I wrote that shows a model / view / controller pattern.

Comment: ITS WORKING!!!! Thank you a lot. I just had to create a Gamemodel instance in the KeyAction class.